# chrome asks for login when printing via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As soon as this page calls the javascript method window.print(), Chrome will show and print it correctly, but it asks for a login, as soon as the print-window is closed. There's nothing in the page linked to a protected directory, and no other Browser asks for a login, only Chrome. When I remove the javascript call, it's fine. Is there any way to fix that?

http://www.mieth-maschinen.de/print/Kr%C3%A4ne%7CStapler%7CHebezeuge/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the authentication form is triggered by the fact that -- in your [CSS](http://www.mieth-maschinen.de/style.css) -- you're referencing an image which is in a protected location:

```
.trenner {
  background: url("http://www.mieth-maschinen.de/neu/img/trenner.png") no-repeat transparent !important;
  }
```

Because the above code is inside of a `@media print`-block, it'll only get triggered when you print.

Since both printing and authenticating are done through a modal, only one can be shown at a time. In this case: print, then auth.

Simply make sure that http://www.mieth-maschinen.de/neu/img/trenner.png is accessible without needing to authenticate (or, remove it from the CSS).

Comment: thanks a lot, that of course fixed the problem. strange anyway that only Chrome asked for the login, no other browser did.

Comment: @lichtpixel No problem ;) Yes but I suppose that it depends on how each browser handles the auth/print combo. Quite likely, other browsers simply ignore the auth request.

Answer (score 0):

Within your stylesheet, inside a print media query, there's a background image declaration:

```
.trenner {
  background: url("http://www.mieth-maschinen.de/neu/img/trenner.png") no-repeat transparent !important;
}
```

It looks like your Apache configuration forces authentication for accessing that image.

Comment: thanks a lot, that of course fixed the problem. strange anyway that only Chrome asked for the login, no other browser did.